# Black rectangular areas in Chrome (not covering whole screen)

Tags: google-chrome, display

From time to time, I get black rectangles in Chrome browser, all of a sudden. They appear in random places, usually several of them together, and they disappear when I move the mouse over them. As long as I don't move the mouse they stay in place, I was able to catch screenshot now:

> [image]

It happens on all sites, at random times.

I didn't find any viruses or malware, and didn't detect any weird process running.

OS: Windows 10, 64 bit. Chrome 60 but it has been happening for several months now so it spans several versions already.

Comment: This is something that exist in the chromium engine. I do not know exactly how or why, but I'm using Vivaldi, a different browser using the chromium engine, and from time to time I experience the exact same thing.

Comment: @LPChip so I'm surprised it wasn't reported before... all my searches led to problems involving whole black screen.

Comment: Did it dissapear right after you pressed `PrtScr`? If not, maybe next time you can open Inspect Element by pressing F12, and see if it's DOM element. Looks like a Facebook chat window to me... You guys maybe use the same extension that's causing this.

Comment: @doriclazar no it did not disappear. And no facebook extensions, only desktop notifications.

Comment: I use vivaldi on my remote desktop server, which does refresh the screen automatically. The problem usually happens when I have lag on my internet connection, but it is only happening in vivaldi in the exact same way as described above. Seems like an optimization routine bugging due to some network latency problems, but this is pure speculation at this point.

Comment: Thanks @LPChip this makes sense, hope someone can confirm this somehow. :)